# Possible to determine size of android apk to be installed?

Tags: android, installation, apk, space

I want to calculate the space the installed APK needs before the APK installs.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible , you can check this by simply taking ur apk and using analyse ANDROID STUDIO->BUILD->ANALYSE APK tool to see approximate size your apps would take and see exactly why ( available only in android 2.2 and above). and if you simply want to know your apk size,you can simply right click on it and see properties for size.However i like to consider +10% margin to consider space on target device just as buffer.

And if you are talking about space taken up by the data of resources your app will write onto the storage,then that totally depends on your to be stored data size and overheads of storing it

if your looking for phone memory resources stats, you should try using tools such as systrace and memory trace tools available in android studio and run your app on emulator or device to see real time usages

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for the space size called PackageStats.codeSize in android sdk when the apk has installed but not launch never. The problem is I do not know how i can get PackageStats.codeSize when apk is installed  first by coding and not by tool like Android Studio.It is possible by hook or another ?